# Mongrel restarting just one port?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, redmine, mongrel

I have a mongrel cluster setup across six ports. I understand how to restart the cluster.

It would be nice if I could do plugin testing for our Redmine install and not have to interrupt the teams service for restarting mongrel. I was wondering if it's possible to restart just one port that could serve sort as a development port? (On restarts mongrel appears to load in the changes that are made to the rails application.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this is to have a separate deployment for your Redmine plugin testing.  You could use Capistrano multistage to deploy to a different directory on the same server (and use the same `database.yml`).  Then you could restart that instance any time without disturbing the team.